# What do I do to make the TextView (address+postcode) clickable & to open google maps?

Tags: android, textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/address" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:autoLink="map" /> 

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/postcode" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:autoLink="map" /> 

<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple...

Just add onCLickListener on to the TextView..
in the function dont directly call the map activity.
but instaed firstly change the color of textview.
and then using Handler call postDelayed Method to call the Map Activity to have clicking effect

check the code below

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                           myTextView.setTextColor(Color.red);
                           mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

                                public void run()
                                {
                                   // Here call your map activity
                                }  
                             },200L); 
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: if any answer helps you out then accept the answer by selecting the arrow on left side so that others can get a benefit also

Comment: Given that the OP specifically asked how to open the Google Maps app it would be really helpful if you could include that code in your answer. I believe the OP wants to automatically pass the text in the textview as a search string to Google Maps.